# trigger jenkins to start build when dev branch merge to master

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have trouble with my task. I use multibranch Jenkins pipeline, and I want that build start automatically when I merge dev branch to master. I tried to find some solution but I was fail. Plase help me resolve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: which SCM host repo you are using? like bitbucket,gitlab etc. you need to configure a webhook on merge in repository settings.

Comment: Add some info to your question about the repo-manager are using: e.g. Github, Bitbucket etc. 
Also, have you looked at webhooks that are possible with those?

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub as SCM you can create webhooks and select individual events for which you want to trigger the pipeline.

In Jenkins multibranch pipeline select the respective repository name.

Not sure if this is the answer to your question.

Comment: I configured webhooks and select push, but as I understand I need to configure pipeline too,I mean that I need to configure some script, but I cant find correct command.

Answer (score 0):

I configured webhooks and select push, but as I understand I need to configure pipeline too,I mean that I need to configure some script, but I cant find correct command.

Comment: can you share the webhook and pipeline details?

Comment: https://github.com/skorik-kirill/helmcharts/blob/master/Jenkinsfile